# Split a table based on two columns value

Tags: mysql

Is there anyway to split a table based on two columns value? So, in the following example, if rows have same ID and that ID contains both car and bike in column Type, then I would like to create a table named 'All'. However, if that ID only contains Bike, then I need to create a table named 'Bike'. The same for Car.

Find below an example input table for your reference:

| ID | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 75 | Car | 1/1/2021 |
| 75 | Bike | 1/1/2020 |
| 54 | Bike | 1/2/2019 |
| 71 | Car | 3/1/2021 |
| 51 | Bike | 5/2/2019 |
| 51 | Bike | 5/2/2017 |

The expected output is the following:
Table All:
| ID | Type | Date    |
|:---|:----:|--------:|
| 75 | Car  | 1/1/2021|
| 75 | Bike | 1/1/2020|

Table Bike:
| ID | Type | Date    |
|:---|:----:|--------:|
| 54 | Bike | 1/2/2019|
| 51 | Bike | 5/2/2019|
| 51 | Bike | 5/2/2017|

Table Car:
| ID | Type | Date    |
|:---|:----:|--------:|
| 71 | Car  | 3/1/2021|

Many thanks.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE Bike AS SELECT * FROM All WHERE Type='Bike'` for example. If the `All` table gets updated, you might consider using a `VIEW`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. However, I've missed something. In case an ID contains both Car and Bike, that Bike's row cannot be moved to the Bike's table but to the All one.

Comment: Oh OK, sorry, that's WAY more difficult :)

Comment: Temp table: `SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(Type)) AS Types, date FROM table GROUP BY id, date`. You can then split the resulting table based on the new Types field.

Comment: Thanks! Let me analyze that expression becuase it is not familiar for me.

Comment: Barry, I don't really understand your solution. If I'm not wrong, your code concat unique values of Type and group them by Id and date. But, the output is same table sorted by ID.. I have a lot of rows so, I don't know how to then split that output table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247032/discussion-between-alex-and-barry-carter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your kind support, Barry. Below, your solution:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS 
SELECT id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(Type)) AS Types 
FROM table5 
GROUP BY id;
```

And then create as many tables as values has the "*Type*" columns. Below is the table for the "*Bikes*".

```
CREATE TABLE Bike AS 
SELECT * 
FROM table5 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM newtable WHERE Types = 'Bike');
```